# OpenAPI Generator: How to fix WARN o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - The value (generator's option) must be either boolean or string. Default to `false`

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I am using the following OpenAPI commands to generate client using [openapi-generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/installation/):

```
npx @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i api.yaml -g cpp-restsdk -o  %CD%
```

after running the command why it shows the following warning:

```
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - The value (generator's option) must be either boolean or string. Default to `false`.
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have a full answer for you; but for reference - the piece of code that generates that message is [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/9deeb608e656a3779d96e7ea2e83835ac40b26b1/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/DefaultCodegen.java#L6889) (Github)

```
public boolean convertPropertyToBoolean(String propertyKey) {
     final Object booleanValue = additionalProperties.get(propertyKey);
     boolean result = Boolean.FALSE;
     if (booleanValue instanceof Boolean) {
        result = (Boolean) booleanValue;
     } else if (booleanValue instanceof String) {
        result = Boolean.parseBoolean((String) booleanValue);
     } else {
        LOGGER.warn("The value (generator's option) must be either boolean or string. Default to `false`.");
     }
     return result;
}
```

You can see the message occurs when you try to covert a value to bool that is not string/bool (likely because it is undefined).

I had a quick play around manually declaring options I found in the angular code generator ([here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/languages/TypeScriptAngularClientCodegen.java)) but couldn't narrow it down; leading me to think:

1. It's a conversion happening higher up in the generic generation code (not typescript-angular specific)
2. It's a not a conversion happening in the config property processing where I was testing (maybe its command line params etc)

Either way, you are probably safe to ignore it since it's only a warning and the conversion will still result in a value (default: false). If its from an option you didn't set then you are probably happy with the default value!